# Plus and Minus Values from Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table Shape:

```
---------------------------------------
ProductID   |   Reference   |   Qty   |
---------------------------------------
1           |    Plus       |    8    |
---------------------------------------
1           |    Minus      |    2    |
---------------------------------------
2           |    Plus       |    18   |
---------------------------------------
2           |    Minus      |    6    |
---------------------------------------
2           |    Minus      |    3    |
---------------------------------------
```

Result Will be like This.

```
----------------------------
ProductID   |   Rem. Qty   |
----------------------------
1           |      6       |
----------------------------
2           |      9       |
----------------------------
```

Comment: Great!  What's the query that you'll run to get that result?

Comment: What your suggestion to get the result like this?

Comment: What was wrong with your own attempt? Did you get an error? Please do show us so we can you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Reference = 'Plus' THEN Qty ELSE -1.0 * Qty END) AS Total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ProductID;
```

Comment: Is there any reason why everybody uses `-1.0 * Qty` instead of a simple `-Qty`?

Comment: @dnoeth For some reason, I recall seeing some SO questions on databases where `-Qty` would be a syntax error.  Maybe not necessary here, but I did it just to be safe.

Comment: @dnoeth Some database do not like the syntax `-Qty`.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Interesting, seems to be badly implemented parsing rules. Can you name one of those DBMSes?

Comment: Agreed Tim, First time I post the question here, have no idea how many steps to follow etc. Thanks for your answer much appreciated!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The right tag added, Not sure about `vb.net`.

Comment: @dnoeth: If I remember correctly I encountered such syntax errors with `-column` back in the days on Oracle 8i or 9i or SQL Sever 2000 or 2005. If you can dig up these dinosaurs anywhere, you can try it.

Comment: @stickybit: Noooo, I'm glad those days are over :-)

Comment: In most languages unary negation has a higher precedence than other arithmetic operators. SQL Server didn't get it right, but eventually Microsoft chose to correct the documentation rather than the functionality (aka make a "breaking change"). You can see the power of it in the following two queries which return `2` and `divide by zero`: `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / -3 / 5;`.